# Find index corresponding to values in multiple vectors

Tags: c++

I have 4 vectors v1, v2, v3 and v4.

I want to find k such that v1[k]==a1, v2[k]==a2, v3[k]==a3 and v4[k]==a4 (where a1,a2,a3,a4 are known values). Such a k is guaranteed to exist and be unique in this situation.

I could write a series of for loops to do this (find the indices in one list, then check those indices in the next list and so on until there is only one index remaining), but is there a built in method in C++ for doing this? If it makes any difference, I'm not interested in what the value of k is, I just want to remove the kth entry from each list.

Comment: Note: only one `for` loop is needed to find `k`.`for (k=0,;...){\\if (v1[k]!=a1)continue;\\if (v2[k]!=a2)continue;...`

Comment: Ah yeah, that's true. Maybe I should stop being lazy and just do it myself....

Comment: ... or `if(v1[k]==a1 && v2[k] == a2 && v3[k] == a3 && v4[k] == a4) return k;` - short-circuit evaluation will stop the comparison as soon as one condition (from left to right) is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [std::find()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [zip_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) from Boost:

```
const auto iter_first = boost::make_zip_iterator(v1.begin(), v2.begin(), v3.begin(), v4.begin());
const auto iter_last = boost::make_zip_iterator(v1.end(), v2.end(), v3.end(), v4.end());
const auto iter_k = std::find(iter_first, iter_last, boost::make_tuple(a1, a2, a3, a4));
v1.erase(iter_k.get_iterator_tuple().get<0>());
v2.erase(iter_k.get_iterator_tuple().get<1>());
v3.erase(iter_k.get_iterator_tuple().get<2>());
v4.erase(iter_k.get_iterator_tuple().get<3>());
```

There's no `zip_iterator` in STL yet (not even in the new ranges library).

I suppose you can do the same via `zip_view` from [ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) instead of Boost.